# Как версионировать ПО, которое состоит из нескольких модулей с использованием Git?

Tags: контроль-версий, devops

У меня есть абстрактное приложение, которое состоит из нескольких независимых модулей на разных языках. Я хочу использовать Git Submodules для версионирования: тогда у меня будет основной репозиторий, где хранится документация и конфиги docker-compose, и папки, куда Git тащит мои приложения из всех репозиториев.

Проблема: во время разработки, что бы протестировать новую фичу, мне придется проходить следующем путем: сделать коммит в репозиторий приложения, сделать push, потом обновить submodules в главном репозитории и только тогда поднимать. А если что то сломается, мне надо будет откатывать коммит (что особенно актуально когда разработка только начинается, и таких правок сотни).

Второй вариант - создать подпапки в репозитории, но это приведет к тому что коммиты будут смешиваться. Более того, это может ломать IDE и системы управления зависимостями (например, модули Golangа будут плохо себя чувствовать, а системы контроля версий интегрированные в IDE могут чувствовать себя плохо).

Есть ли какая то альтернатива или гибридный подход к управлению зависимостями приложений из нескольких модулей?

Comment: Что-то я не совсем понял, что ломает второй вариант и почему кто-то будет себя плохо чувствовать. Крупные компании как раз держат всё в одном большом репозитории, на всю операционную систему Windows со всеми компонентами тоже приходится один монорепозиторий :)

Comment: @andreymal ну, например, я делаю коммит в mainRep/moduleA. А потом в mainRep/moduleB. В итоге на вкладочке комитов я увижу кашу из разных приложений. Еще это ломает систему пакетов голанга (там есть костыль, но это некрасиво). Кроме того, я не уверен, нормально ли будет работать IDE (я пользуюсь VS Code и продуктами Jetbrains'a) тогда, когда в папке папке проекта нет репозитория.

Comment: В описаниях коммитов обычно в начале приписывают префикс с названием компонента чтобы не путаться, например https://github.com/reactos/reactos/commits/master | Ну а проблемы голанга это проблемы голанга, в нормально спроектированных языках никаких проблем с пакетами нет ;)

Comment: @andreymal это, конечно, справедлво, но проблема остается. А IDE будут нормально работать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть 3 вариант,

1. Создайте для каждого автономного модуля отдельный репозиторий. Что бы программисты могла работать только в 1м проекте.
2. Создайте ветки Developer и production для каждого проекта. Когда есть логическая концовка заливаете из Developer на Production.
3. Создайте пользователя для devops в роли Reporter. Что бы с эго имени можно было клонировать проект
4. Создаете bash файл, который из каждого проекта берет ветку production и компилирует. Думаю компилятор у вас через терминал запускается.
5. Потом дальше удаляет старые версии и ставил новую и перезапускает службы.

пример

```
export gitUrl="$gitBaseUrl/project.git"
export gitBranch="production"

gitclone() {
    echo "Cloning project $projectName..."
    rm -rf $projectFolder
    mkdir -p $projectFolder
    git clone --branch $gitBranch $gitUrl $projectFolder
}
```